# Post count for particular term

Tags: custom-post-types

I am making by wonderful page and I want to query a given custom post type called accommodations and display the number of posts in that given location and this what I have e.g (1,110) Accommodation in Newyork

```
<?php
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'accommodations',
'taxonomy' => 'location',
'field' => 'NewYork'
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
echo $the_query->found_posts;
?>
```

but it gives me everything in that custom post type instead

Comment: Display the posts or the number of posts?

Comment: What does `(1,110)` stand for ?

Comment: aha, I thought this was a 2-tuple `(x,y)`, since I'm used to `1.100`, with dot as a thousand seperator ;-)

Comment: @birgire that is 1100 posts. Don't get mathematical here, hahahaha. ;-) (*Just pulling your leg*)

Comment: hehe I thought 110 was the NewYork term count, but I was scratching my head about the meaning of a "single" accommodation - sorry I just got carried away from the question, by a single comma ;-) I think @PieterGoosen solution will work out for you.

Answer (score 1):

Your query is completely wrong. You should use a proper `tax_query`. Also note, your query is quite expensive to run to just count posts. Set the `fields` paremeter to only return post ID's. This saves up to 99.9% on resources.

Just a note, the field parameter inside a `tax_query` is important. The valid values are `slug`, `term_id` and `name`. This value must correspond with the value passed to the `terms` parameter. So, if fields are set to `slug`, you must pass the term slug to `terms`. Do not use the `name` parameter, there is a bug in the `WP_Tax_Query` class where the query fails if a term's name consists of more than one word.

You can try the following

```
 $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'accommodations',
    'no_paging' => true, // Gets all posts
    'fields' => 'ids', // Gets only the post ID's, saves on resources
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'location', // Taxonomy name
            'field' => 'slug', // Field to check, valid values are term_id, slug and name
            'terms' => 'new-york' // This value must correspond to field value. If slug, use term slug
        )
    ),
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
echo $the_query->found_posts;
```

Comment: Please consider the following: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). Thank you :-)

Comment: Do you still have any issue regarding the code above?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question

> display the number of posts

```
$published_posts = wp_count_posts('accommodations')->publish;
```

This will give you the number of posts published for the accommodations post type.

Comment: It will but it will give me for all accommodations I have entered yet I want only accommodations in New York